# EJB jar don't detect shared library in EAr in weblogic server 10.3.4

Tags: java, ejb, weblogic

I have a Maven application in Weblogic 10.3.4 that's giving this error:

```
EJB Exception: : java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: bo/si/common/email/EnviarCorreo at org.osbo.EjbPrueba.prueba(EjbPrueba.java:23) at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39) at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25) at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597) at com.bea.core.repackaged.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:310) at com.bea.core.repackaged.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:182) at com.bea.core.repackaged.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:149) at com.bea.core.repackaged.springframework.aop.support.DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.doProceed(DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.java:131) at com.bea.core.repackaged.springframework.aop.support.DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.invoke(DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.java:119) at com.bea.core.repackaged.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:171) at com.bea.core.repackaged.springframework.jee.spi.MethodInvocationVisitorImpl.visit(MethodInvocationVisitorImpl.jav
```

In EJB *jar*, I have this code in *weblogic-application* of *ear*:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<weblogic-application xmlns="http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-application" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/javaee_5.xsd http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-application http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-application/1.0/weblogic-application.xsd">
    <library-ref>
        <library-name>SiSharedLibrary</library-name>
        <specification-version>1.0.0</specification-version>
        <exact-match>false</exact-match>
    </library-ref>
</weblogic-application>
```

I have a *war* module in *ear* with code in *weblogic.xml*:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<weblogic-web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app/1.0/weblogic-web-app.xsd">
    <jsp-descriptor>
        <keepgenerated>true</keepgenerated>
        <debug>true</debug>
    </jsp-descriptor>
    <context-root>/mavenproject3-web</context-root>
    <library-ref>
        <library-name>SiSharedLibrary</library-name>
        <specification-version>1.0.0</specification-version>
        <exact-match>false</exact-match>
    </library-ref>

</weblogic-web-app>
```

I have error in EJB, but in *war* the same code not, why? Any ideas?

The structure of *ear* is:

```
mavenproject3-ear
   |
   |- mavenproject3-ejb.jar
   |
   |- mavenproject3-web.war
```

Comment: Could you please elaborate more on *...i have error in EJB , but in war the same code not...*. Do you have the same call on your EJB *jar* and on your *war*?

Comment: what kind of file is your shared library ?

Comment: ehm EJB call shared library, war too how? with create intanse of class in shared library of weblogic.
EJB error class def Exception
war run perfectly

why?

Comment: @devwebcl shared library is a feature of weblogic for deploy libraries that share the java EE apps in weblogic, is exclusive in weblogic

Comment: @programmercito yes, I know that WLS feature, however it can be any of:
- standalone EJB module
- standalone Web application module
- multiple EJB modules packaged in an Enterprise application
- multiple Web application modules package in an Enterprise application
- single plain JAR file

So, my question was referring to that.

Comment: ohhh yes only a EJB is called from war, but in EJB dont recognice the clases o librarys in shared library of weblogic , but in war yes

Comment: sorry for my English